# Laravel 8 problem with pass variable from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this error, my question is. Can't pass a variable from UsersController from function userscontroller_show if the view returns function userscontroll from Dashboardcheck?

> $query is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade template.
> Replace {{ $query }} with {{ $query ?? '' }}

Web file.
Route to function who show data from database

```
Route::get('/userscontrollers', [UsersController::class, 'userscontroller_show']);
```

Route to function who returns view:

```
Route::get('/userscontrollers', [Dashboardcheck::class, 'userscontroll']);
```

UsersControllers Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function userscontroller_show(){
        $query = DB::table('user')
        ->select('id_users', 'nick_user', 'email_user', 'verification_user')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
        return view('Pages.Dashboard.usercontroll', compact('query'));
    }

    protected function userscontroller_update(){

    }
}
```

Dashboardcheck Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
class Dashboardcheck extends Controller
{
    function login(){
        if(Session::has('user')){
            return view('Pages.dashboard');
        }else{
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
    function userscontroll(){
        if(Session::has('user')){
            $query = DB::table('user')
            ->select(DB::raw('*'))
            ->where('nick_user', Session::get('user'))
            ->first();
            if($query->user_permission >= 4){
                return view('Pages.Dashboard.usercontroll');
            }else{
                return redirect('/dashboard')->with('alert', 'Nie posiadasz uprawnien do przeglądania tych treści');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't have two identical routes for `/userscontrollers`. Laravel has no way to know which route you want to use, so it will only use the first route every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update you routes. You cannot have similar route.
Update this line of code in `Dashboardcheck Controller`.

```
return view('Pages.Dashboard.usercontroll', compact('query'));
```

You did not pass any `$query` variable. So it is showing error.

Comment: Why? I wanna pass $query from UsersController. In Dashboardcheck Controller I have only check if user have privileges and return view

Comment: If you do not want to pass `$query` then you have to check that variable is set and not null in blade. If not set or null then return else block. Use if else.

Comment: I wanna pass $query but from UsersControllers Controller. But my view is return in Dashboardcheck Controller

Comment: Put a if else condition in blade.